# How to manage Encoding Problems with äöü in email send through smtp?

Tags: encoding, smtp

I have send an email äöü in E-Mail Notifications (Video Title) Example: Vielseitigkeit-Europameisterschaft 2011: Freya Fllgraebe 1 ist nun in der Kategorie.thats word äöü is changes into Fllgraebe.How to remain same äöü when we send mail through smtp in php?

Comment: Could you name your email client or programming language/environment? I think you want specific fix instead of general explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The MIME specifications define various encoding algorithms for this depending on whether the text appears in the message body, one of the message headers, or in parameters to the Content-Type/Content-Disposition headers (such as filename).

All of the MIME specifications are hosted on [www.ietf.org](http://www.ietf.org). For a set of quick links, check out https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/RFCs.md

Answer (score 0):

Add some headers to you e-mail declaring the encoding you are using. Assuming you are using UTF-8 use the following headers

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```